# Slight smudge in Indian passport's officer stamp, can I travel with this?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, passport-stamps

I have got my decision letter from Norway for Work permit. I had submitted the same passport with this smudge. Now only stamping is pending, just noticed this, will this create a problem? Can they reject my visa based on this?[image]

Comment: There’s nothing you can do. You’ve already submitted. Just think positive

Comment: Update: Thanks guys for the answers, I did travel without any problems, Like one of the answer says, **No body cared**, They only checked the important info pages. 

Answer (score 10):

**Nobody cares.**  Ink smudges, and passport pages closed soon after stamping very easily cause the stamp to smudge.  Everybody dealing with passports is aware of this and accepts it.  I have many stamps in my passports that are effectively illegible, some not just smudged but stamped at an angle so that eg. one edge is missing completely, and I've never had a single question at Immigration about these.

Just about the only possible exception to this is **if the smudge hides critical information**, eg. how long your visa is valid for or what the start/end dates are.  But even this is less important now, since immigration systems are computerized and they can check your electronic records if the stamps are unclear.

In your case, though, the stamp is effectively purely decorative (most countries do *not* stamp their own passports at all) and will have no impact on your application.