# Water spilled on passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, hong-kong

Passport was got wet in the rain. water was spilled over the stamp but identification page are intect and has no issue will there be any issue?[image]

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80198/passport-book-cover-is-slightly-detached-from-page

Comment: Doesn't matter. See here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172389/slight-smudge-in-indian-passports-officer-stamp-can-i-travel-with-this#172391